# One-class svm with given true positive rate

Tags: classification, cross-validation, svm, libsvm, one-class

Is it always possible to find a one-class SVM with given true positive rate (TPR)?
I used 1-D grid search with cross-validation to find the width parameter of RBF kernel with .90 TPR.  The closest model I found has average .79 TPR using cross-validation.  I am not talking about the prediction on unseen data yet; just the cross-validation performance.  Using the code below I find bestcv = 0.79 but I want a one-class SVM with near 0.9 bestcv!

> % Each row of X contains a signals (has N rows), Row vector labs is
>   % vector of N ones, '-s 2' means one-class SVM, '-t 2' means RBF kernel
>   % which g is its parameter of. '-v 5' means use 5-fold cross-validation. libsvm-3.22 syntax
>
> > bestdif = inf; tpr = 0.9;
> >     for log2g = -50:.125:10
> >
> > > cmd = ['-t 2 -s 2 -g ' num2str(2^log2g) ' -v ' 5];
> > >       cv  = svmtrain(labs, X, cmd);
> > >       dif = abs(cv-tpr);
> > >       if dif <= bestdif
> > >
> > > > ```
> > > >  bestdif = dif;  
> > > >  bestg   = 2^log2g;  
> > > >  bestcv  = cv;
> > > > ```
> > > >
> > > > end
> > > >         end

Comment: Could you describe your procedure in greater detail? From your description I do not understand what you were doing and why?

Comment: @tim I added details ...